# JSON file not showing up on Godaddy server

Tags: android, json

I followed this tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/) and created my own JSON feed but when I try to view it with the Android app or a web browser I get a "404 file not found" error. I know that's not correct because I've checked the file structure in my file structure on the server and it's correct. What is causing the JSON file to not be seen or readable? Is there something else I need to do on the GoDaddy server first?

Comment: Did you give the right URL? Post the code where you actually fetch the data.

Comment: `rsrc.json` is really in the document root of `http://api.almosthomevethousing.com/`?

Comment: If you click the first link at the very top for the tutorial, the code from the tutorial is the same. The only thing I changed was the url for the json file which is at the JSON hyperlink above. When I tested it with the tut's json file everything worked perfectly. Even viewing the json from a browser. My json file is not even viewable through a browser.

Comment: @Drakes yes. Is that bad?

Comment: No, but your other assets are 404'd too, http://api.almosthomevethousing.com/css/customer-comp.css for example. Does api redirect somewhere?

Comment: @Drakes I've checked all other files within that directory(which aren't many) and none of them come up with a 404 error

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it, but `/images/404_background.jpg` and `/css/customer-comp.css` still show as 404'd resources when you go to http://api.almosthomevethousing.com/ directly - title is "Future home of something quite cool.".

Comment: in godaday plesk .. Goto IIS Setting-> add "application/json json" in allowed mime type .. it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my issue. With GoDaddy hosting, you have to add the MIME type to the server settings. Once I did that, everything worked perfectly. Here's the link for anyone having similar issues. Walks you through adding the MIME type.

[Adding .json handler support](http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/)

[Specific instructions for GoDaddy](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6286/modifying-or-adding-custom-mime-types-to-windows-hosting-accounts?locale=en)

Comment: neither of these links work anymore, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The json you posted seems to be corrupt.

See line 10  **`"url": http://vethunters.org/`**

Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

Similar is the case with line 24 
**`"image": "http://api.almosthomevethousing.com/feed/img/vetparentingimage.jpg`**
Missing closing quotes.

You can validate JSON with sites like JSONLint to ensure its not corrupt.